# /usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, windows, ubuntu, nodemon

I know this question has been asked many times, but none of the solutions worked for me. I'm desperate!
On Windows 10, I've created a simple Vue.js & Node app, following this guide:

[Full Stack Web App using Vue.js & Express.js](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fa4cRMaTDUI)

which implements a simple client/server app.

After I installed nodemon, I try to run "npm start" and got this:

> /usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory

I saw that on the top of nodemon.js file I have this following line:

> #!/usr/bin/env node

I know that this is a shebang line.

several questions:

1. How do I solve this??
2. Why is this line even there? is it because I have Ubunto app from windows store installed?
3. I also have "Remote - WSL" package installed on VSCODE. Maybe related?

What I already tried:

1. On Ubunto app for windows, I ran the following:

> sudo ln -sfn /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node

1. On windows environment variables I added C:\Program Files\nodejs to both user and system variables
2. On the nodemon.js file, I tried to change the

> #!/usr/bin/env node

to

> #!C:\Progra~1\nodejs\node.exe

Nothing helps!

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it. The issue was that the terminal I worked with wasn't bash. ‍♂️
Silly me.